# Change tuple values when using a loop in pine script

Tags: function, loops, tuples, pine-script

In pine script I have a funtion that returns a tuple:

```
calcSomething(val1, val2) =>
    ...
    [val3, val4]
```

And I'm calling the function from a loop where the **val1** and **val2** change:

```
while i < 5
    [val5, val6] = calcSomething(val1, val2)
    val1 += 1
    val2 += 1
    i += 1
```

Unfortunately the values from **val5** and **val6** remain the same every time the loop runs.

I tried to change "="

```
[val5, val6] = calcSomething(val1, val2)
```

to ":="

```
[val5, val6] := calcSomething(val1, val2)
```

But it returns a Syntax error at input ':='.

How can the tuple change values from inside a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the `:=` operator with tuples yet.

A workaround is to use two temporary variables:

```
while i < 5
    [_val5, _val6] = calcSomething(val1, val2)
    val5 := _val5
    val6 := _val6
    val1 := val1 + 1
    val2 := val2 + 1
    i := i + 1
```